# Unable to retrieve objects from Parse due to error on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have been using my app during the day with no issues but I am now getting the following error on all requests I make to Parse to get objects:

```
2014-09-03 20:24:21.913 App[3407:332f] Error: Failed to initialize mongo connection (Code: 159, Version: 1.2.20)
```

Has anyone else experienced this and if so know the reason behind the message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would appear Parse has just gone down as it's now coming up when going to the data browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Parse is down once again (no surprise)  Here is the link to the new bug if you are having the same problem of mongo DB going down.  The twitter and status website should be the same.  Hopefully they fix this sooner rather than later.......

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/665440236886829/

I am having the same problem and posted on the developers website you can follow it here.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/300758356778621/

Edit: They are experience a lot of different problems it sounds like right now.  Facebook was down for awhile but is now up. They are still working on parse errors and crashes according to what the developer left on the link above.

So it is coming up slowly but people are still experiencing errors on top of following the bug at the link above here is there twitter account.

https://twitter.com/ParseStatus

Also their status website.

http://status.parse.com/incidents/m9k6y5qbz2dk

Should be up shortly (hopefully).

Comment: Cheers Steven, I have also tweeted at them to ensure they are aware.

Comment: Glad I am not alone.  Thanks Richard